# Is a static variadic template friend function legal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, friend

I need to ensure a class is always produced as a `shared_ptr`. I thus use the idiomatic factory pattern for this:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Base {

  public:
    template <typename Device, typename... Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<Device> create_shared(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Device>(new Device(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

  protected:
    Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {

  private:
    template <typename Device, typename... Args>
    friend std::shared_ptr<Device> Base::create_shared(Args&&... args);

    Derived()
        : Base()
    {
    }
};

int main(int, char**) { auto d{Base::create_shared<Derived>()}; }
```

Link https://godbolt.org/z/f7oz15ren

The above compiles on GCC, but not on MSVC.
Changing a few things resolves the issue (on MSVC).

1. Move the `create_shared` out of the class to become a *free function*: https://godbolt.org/z/M65n34ena
2. Remove the *variadic args* from the template: https://godbolt.org/z/bEcnPfbhv

I can of course just make it a free function and get on with it, but I'm curious if this is actually an ill-formed C++ program or the compiler is making a mistake here.

Any guru fluent in standardise that can help me out here?

Comment: Yes it is : https://godbolt.org/z/nqYG96aPh just some small changes to main. And added a function call to show the call can also be made. Though I personally prefer a freestanding factory function.

Comment: Please include the errors you are getting in the question.

Comment: [Passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) might be simpler.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, You cheated. You use GCC in your example, but I only had the issue with MSVC.
Here is your example with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/hn56nMs3d

Comment: @Jarod42, it might, but it doesn't answer _this_ question.

Comment: That's why it is a comment ;-)

Comment: Without variadic, all passes [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x97j7K1K3)

Comment: @Jarod42, that's what my second point illustrated. But thanks for adding clang to the pool :)

Comment: It's an MSVC bug.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, Could you point to where in the standard this doesn't work and make it into an answer so we can close this one?

Comment: One, the error message makes no sense at all. Two, there is dimply nothing in the standard that would single out a variadic template in this position.